# What is wrong with this procedural function to add numbers 1 through n?

Tags: functions, function-construction

I am trying to write a function to add numbers from 1 through h:

```
function[h_]:= x=0; For[i=1, i=<h, i++, x = x + i]; Print[x]
```

But I am getting some strange and inconsistent results. Can someone point out what is wrong here?

Comment: put the right-hand side in parantheses: i.e., `function[h_] := (x = 0; For[i = 1, i <= h, i++, x = x + i]; Print[x])`. Btw, you don't need to use `Print[x]`, you can use just `x` instead.

Comment: Thanks alot. Why were the parenthesis necessary?

Comment: without the parentheses, you are defining `function` as `function[h_] := x = 0;` and the remaining parts are executed as independent expressions: part `For[i = 1, i <= h, i++, x = x + i]` does not do anything to `x` (because `h` is not given a value) and  `Print[x]` is executed separately and prints `0`.

Comment: Aahhhh ok. Thanks for making this clear. If you write this as an answer, I'd be happy to give you credit for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the expressions on right-hand-side in parentheses:

```
function[h_] := (x = 0; For[i = 1, i <= h, i++, x = x + i]; Print[x])

function[10]
```

> 55

Without the parentheses,  you are defining `function`  as `function[h_] := x = 0;` and the remaining expressions are not part of the definition of `function`.

As mentioned by m_goldberg, there are better ways to define such a function. In addition to the ones in m_goldberg's answer, you can also use

```
ClearAll[function]
function[h_]:= h (h + 1) / 2

function[10]
```

> 55

Comment: Indeed, here we employ (a special case of) the formula for the [sum of an arithmetic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum).

Answer (score 6):

This is not an answer within the constraints of you question, but I think you should be made aware that there are much better ways.

A simple and functional way to write your function in the Wolfram Language would be

```
function[h_] := Total @ Range[h]
```

Then

```
function[10]
```

returns (and prints)

`>`55`

This version of `function` is not only more concise than your procedural code, it is many times faster.

Of course, the built-in function `Sum` is even more concise.

```
Sum[x, {x, 10}]
```

> `55`

But `Sum` works symbolically, so it be used to define an extremely efficient version of `function`.

```
Block[{x, h}, function[h_] = Sum[x, {x, h}]];
```

This gives the definition

```
Definition @ function
```

> `function[h_] = 1/2 h (1 + h)`

which is about as good as you can get.

Comment: Might be worth to mention `PolygonalNumber` as built-in solution